# Inner join then full join among the matched records

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

I have two tables:

```
declare @Table1 as table (id int, value CHAR(1))
declare @Table2 as table (id int, value CHAR(1))

INSERT @Table1
VALUES (1, 'A'),
(1, 'B'),
(3, 'A')

INSERT @Table2
VALUES(1, 'A'),
(1, 'C'),
(2, 'A')
```

I want to join these two tables so that at the end I should be able to produce this result:

```
id     value    id      value
1      A        1       A
1      B        NULL    NULL
NULL   NULL     1       C
```

I'm sorry for inadequate explanation (I mean no explanation at all). What I am trying to do here is (something like) to make inner join for the id columns (I mean take the records which are common on both sets over the "id" column) then look at the value columns and compare them inside the boundaries of this common set.

I hope I could describe what I was trying to do.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Where did the (`3, 'A'`) values from `@Table1` go (or why aren't those showing?). Or yet another way: **why** are you showing `(1, 'B')` from `@Table1` that doesn't exist in `@Table2`, but the `(3, 'A')` isn't being shown.... doesn't really make a lot of sense. .....

Comment: He want to do a side by side comparing. That was what i could undestand. 1 A is in both table so it show side by side; 1 B is only on @table1 but not on table2... I think he misses 3 A from table1

Comment: I'm sorry for inadequate explanation (I mean no explanation at all).

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will work

```
SELECT distinct t1_id as id, t1_value as value , t2_id as id , t2_value as value
FROM (SELECT t1.id as t1_id, t1.value as t1_value from @Table1  t1 INNER JOIN @Table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id) as A 
        FULL OUTER JOIN 
     (SELECT  t2.id as t2_id, t2.value as t2_value  from @Table1  t1 INNER JOIN  @Table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id) as B
    on A.t1_value = B.t2_value
ORDER BY t1_id desc
```

Basically, What I am doing is outer joining the inner set (which is inner join on id column) on value column of inner set.

Answer (score 0):

What do I win?

```
SELECT c.id,c.value,d.id,d.value

FROM
    @Table1 c
    full join
    @Table2 d 
        on c.id = d.id and c.value = d.value
WHERE exists
        (
        SELECT a.id
            FROM
                @Table1 a
            INNER JOIN
                @Table2 b
                  ON a.id = b.id and a.id = c.id or d.id = a.id

        )
```

Comment: working fine in SSMS. I note the preview pane only shows 2 columns

Comment: It seems your tool cannot render identically names results columns - try using an alias

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a `full outer join` *and* by pre-filtering the tables:

```
select a.id as a_id, a.value as a_value,
       b.id as b_id, b.value as b_value
from (select *
      from tablea a
      where a.id = 1
     ) a full outer join
     (select *
      from tableb b
      where b.id = 1
     ) b
     on a.id = b.id and a.value = b.value;
```

Comment: This will only work for records where ID = 1, but not as a rule for records that are common to both tables, no?